# /api not diwplayed well in symfony application

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

i created symfony6 project and try to apply api patform. when i launch http://127.0.0.1:8000/api i got a json response with this error  **'An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Symfony\Component\AssetMapper\Compiler\JavaScriptImportPathCompiler::compile(): Return value must be of type string, null returned").'**
i installed api by the commans symfony require api.
i was expecting the launch of api/platform interface .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, uninstall asset mapper and stimilus

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).